# Unable to create bootable

Tags: release-hera, boot, usb, error

Used Rufus for creating bootable file of hera 5. But it always shows error.It shows 'Unable to download file'. Please fix this as early as possible.

Comment: Make sure you download the right .iso and then verify the .iso - and don't use Rufus - use Balena Etcher instead. There have been numerous issues lately where Rufus is the cause. I assume they're working on it, but Balena Etcher is free and does the job just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible a problem with Rufus, not with elementary OS. You could download the elementary ISO yourself here: https://elementary.io/

After that you can point to the downloaded image from Rufus. You could also use another tool like YUMI, UnetBootin or Balena Etcher.